# docker-compose with docker-swarm under docker-machine not mounting volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I have a working `docker-compose` example running a static html with `nginx`.

The directory tree:

```
├── docker-compose.yml
├── nginx
│   ├── app
│   │   └── index.html
│   └── Dockerfile
```

The `docker-compose.yml`:

```
nginx:
  build: ./nginx
  volumes:
    - ./nginx/app:/usr/share/nginx/html
  ports:
    - 8080:80
```

The `nginx` directory has the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nginx
```

Everything is working right.

The problem is that I build a `Docker-Swarm` infrastructure with `docker-machine` following the Docker documentation: The `Local`, the `swarm-master` and `two nodes`.

Everything seems to work fine too.

```
$ eval $(docker-machine env --swarm swarm-master)
$[swarm-master]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                  NAMES
d8afafeb9f05        few_nginx           "nginx -g 'daemon off"   20 minutes ago      Up 3 seconds        443/tcp, 192.168.99.102:8080->80/tcp   swarm-host-00/few_nginx_1
```

But `nginx` is returning a `Forbidden`

```
$[swarm-master]$ curl http://192.168.99.102:8080/
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.9.10</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I enter into the `virtualbox` and into the `container`:

```
$[swarm-master]$ docker-machine ssh swarm-host-00
docker@swarm-host-00:~$ docker exec -ti d8afafeb9f05 bash
```

and nothing inside the `nginx/html` directory:

```
root@d8afafeb9f05:/# ls /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Is it necessary to do something different in `compose`/`swarm` for the `volumes`? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to copy the files to the hosts or build the image with the `COPY` command into the `Dockerfile`

Reference: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2799#issuecomment-177998133